# Object as variable in new class? Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I'am doing some begginer type OOP exercises found in internet. Currently my task is to create two classes:

- Person: with variables: name, surname, age.
- Song:   with variables: title, author (Person type), date of issue

Problem is how to create this Person type variable.
I tried this:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :surname, :age

  def initialize name, surname, age = nil
    @name, @surname, @age = name, surname, age
  end
end


class Song
  attr_accessor :tite, :author, :date_of_issue

  def initalize title, author , date_of_issue
    @title, @author, @date_of_issue = title, Person.new, date_of_issue
  end
end
```

When I try to create new object:

```
 song1 = Song.new("All_you_need_is_love", "The_beattles", 1967)
```

I get:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

So I got two ideas:

1. My `Song` class code is wrong
2. `song1` object initialization is wrong (because number of arguments)

What do you think?

Comment: How can the `Person` constructor know what the name and the surname are when you don't even give them? You are not passing any parameter to the constructor, but even if you do, are you expecting that Ruby somehow magically selects a player given the group "The_beatles", and extracts, for example "John" and "Lennon" for the name and the surname? If you do, I think you have a completely wrong idea about how Ruby works. It is not an AI.

Answer (score 2):

You should spell `initialize` properly in **Song**. Also consider that the **Person** constructor requires at least 2 arguments.

Comment: Intialize is just misspelled. I was thinking about this two arguments, but don't know how to put them in new song object initialization